# Factorial code not working

Tags: python

Don't know what's wrong, code is giving 12 instead of 24

```
def factorial(x):
    m=x-1
    while m>0:
        t=x*m
        m-=1
        return t
    else:
        return 1
print factorial(4)
```

Comment: Because you're returning on the first iteration of your while loop.

Comment: This is not the only problem, `t=x*m` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

your code return value at first iteration and you assign new value to t every iteration

```
def factorial(x):
...     t = 1
...     while x>0:
...         t *= x
...         x-=1
... 
...     return t
print factorial(4)
output:
24
```

----or----

```
from operator import mul
def factorial(x):
   return reduce(mul, range(1,x+1))
print factorial(4)
output:
24
```

Comment: While OP is apparently using Python 2, it's important to note that the second example won't work as-is on Python 3, as `reduce` is no longer in the std library and has to be imported from `functools`.

Comment: @DeepSpace thank you for point it out. I will write it to my note when I switch to python 3. Thank you

Comment: i got it that my t value keeps changing so the code just returns me the first value.but i dont understand what your code does

Comment: @Anonymous first case when input is 0, return 1. second case when input is not 0, than decrease input by 1 every time till 0. for example, input is 4, x will be 4,3,2,1, 0(not count), t will be 4,12,24,24

Comment: @Anonymous my code is using reduce and mul to do the same

Comment: @galaxyan what is the purpose of t*x

Comment: @Anonymous you are calculating factorial, aren't you?

Comment: @galaxyan yes i am

Comment: @Anonymous t *=x means you are accumulating the result

Comment: in the end, t will be 1*x*(x-1)...*1 (like a factorial(x)*1, if you don't want the last *1 change `while x>0:` to `while x>1:`, *1 is in the `t` already)